# Replacing light fixture

Tags: electrical

I have a wall light attached to a switch.  There are 2 black wires and 1 white wire.  The fixtures as one white white and one black wire.  How do I connect

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the light box?

Answer (score -1):

If you have 3 wires at the light fixture (not including grounding wires)  you need to check voltage, find 120 volts, TURN OFF THE CIRCUIT, connect the white to the neural wire and the black to the wire carrying 120v. Make sure you cap the other wire regardless of the voltage it is carrying, it could be dead because of a disconnect, switch/ breaker etc. Be careful and if you don't understand how to do what I just said, get help.

Comment: If the white is a switch leg making a random change can have cause a direct short.